# Unhandled Exception: type 'WebViewController' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, webview

I would like to ask is there a way that you can parse any value inside the webview textbox... For example i scan qrcode and the result of qrcode i want to be shown in any textbox or textfield or i want to paste the result inside the webview.... but it getting that error and i don't know any metohd to parse the result inside the webview... Is it possible to that? Can someone help me to fix this problem

Scanner

```
  actions: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.all_out),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    String scanning = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
                    setState(() {
                      qrResult = scanning;
                      qrTFResult = scanning;
                      _controller = true;
                      Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: qrResult));
                    });
                  })
            ],
```

WebView

```
 Flexible(
                      flex: 10,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          WebView(
                            initialUrl: '',
                            onPageFinished: (data) {
                              updateLoading(false);
                            },
                            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                            onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
                              _webViewController = webViewController;
                            },
                            gestureRecognizers: Set()
                              ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(
                                  () => TapGestureRecognizer()
                                    ..onTapDown = (tap) async {
                                      print("Has been tap");
                                      final value = await FlutterClipboard.paste();
                                      setState(() {
                                        qrTFResult = value;
                                        qrTFResult = _webViewController as String;
                                      });
                                    })),
                          ),
                          (showLoading)
                              ? Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                )
                              : Center()
                        ],
                      )),
```

Button

```
 floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[400],
            animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
            closeManually: true,
            children: [
              SpeedDialChild(
                  child: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[400],
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_webViewController != null) {
                      _webViewController.goBack();
                    }
                  }),
              SpeedDialChild(
                  child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[400],
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_webViewController != null) {
                      _webViewController.goForward();
                    }
                  }),
              SpeedDialChild(
                  child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[400],
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_webViewController != null) {
                      _webViewController.reload();
                    }
                  }),
              SpeedDialChild(
                  child: Icon(Icons.search),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[400],
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _controller = true;
                    });
                  }),
              SpeedDialChild(
                child: Icon(Icons.paste),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[400],
                onTap: () async {
                  final value = await FlutterClipboard.paste();
                  setState(() {
                    qrTFResult = value;
                    qrTFResult = _webViewController as String;
                  });
                },
```

Comment: `qrTFResult = _webViewController as String;` is the reason. But I don't get what you want to do in this line.

Comment: what i want to do is for example when i scan qrcode the result of qr i want to show in inside google textbox when search.... is it possible to that?